# How to set JPA Eclipse Link connection timeout?

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink

I'm using jpa with eclipse link and my application throw exception when the net work connection is poor i want to increase time out or another solution to this problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this in a query

```
 query.setHint(QueryHints.JDBC_TIMEOUT, x);
```

**Edit:** you can set or override `javax.persistence.query.timeout` by `query.setHint("javax.persistence.query.timeout", x);` but the hint can be not considered in the case of different databases or different persistence providers

Comment: this will required on all queries is there another setting for queries

Comment: what's the different between this hint `uery.setHint(QueryHints.JDBC_TIMEOUT, x);` and the the entity manager factory property `javax.persistence.query.timeout` [QUERY_TIMEOUT](https://eclipse.org/eclipselink/api/2.0/org/eclipse/persistence/config/PersistenceUnitProperties.html#QUERY_TIMEOUT)